# How to automatically resize or reposition controls on a form when the form is resized?

Tags: vb6

So I'm trying to make my form fit to all monitors. Some have different display resolution and scale.

I can resize my form to fit to the display but all properties of its contents don't adjust to that new size.

What I want is if the form is scaled to fit to the display, the controls on the Form should adjust as well. Specifically properties like `Left`, `Top`, `Width`, `Height`, and so one, on every control.

The size could be scaled down or up.

Comment: If what you are saying is you want the `controls` on the Form to adjust when you adjust the Form size, then you're going to have to adjust them all manually..  That is, call `.Move Left, Top, Width, Height` on every control that you want to relocate and/or adjust the size of.

Comment: Did @User51 describe your problem correctly?

Comment: @StayOnTarget Yes, but if i adjust it manually it will takes a lot of time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "adjust it manually" - are you referring to manually writing code to do this? Or to performance at runtime? I think runtime performance would not be any concern. And programming the logic may not be as bad as you think.

Comment: Im not pretty i sure i can do it, because i have tried some of my code and the result my  vb6 stopped. I also lost some of my code :( . What i just want is the form will automatically fit to the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to iterate through all of the controls on the form (mostly) programmatically, rather than having to explicitly adjust each control.  You may have to put in some exceptions for some types of controls (such as timers, which I've put in the example), but generally you can use something like:

```
  Option Explicit

  Private Type ControlInfo_type
    Left As Single
    Top As Single
    Width As Single
    Height As Single
    FontSize As Single
  End Type
  Dim ControlInfos() As ControlInfo_type

Private Sub Form_Load()

  Dim ThisControl As Control
  
  ReDim Preserve ControlInfos(0 To 0)
  ControlInfos(0).Width = Me.Width
  ControlInfos(0).Height = Me.Height
  For Each ThisControl In Me.Controls
    ReDim Preserve ControlInfos(0 To UBound(ControlInfos) + 1)
    On Error Resume Next  ' hack to bypass controls with no size or position properties
    With ControlInfos(UBound(ControlInfos))
      .Left = ThisControl.Left
      .Top = ThisControl.Top
      .Width = ThisControl.Width
      .Height = ThisControl.Height
      .FontSize = ThisControl.FontSize
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
  Next

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()

  Dim ThisControl As Control, HorizRatio As Single, VertRatio As Single, Iter As Integer
  
  If Me.WindowState = vbMinimized Then Exit Sub
  
  HorizRatio = Me.Width / ControlInfos(0).Width
  VertRatio = Me.Height / ControlInfos(0).Height
  
  Iter = 0
  For Each ThisControl In Me.Controls
    Iter = Iter + 1
    On Error Resume Next  ' hack to bypass controls
    With ThisControl
      .Left = ControlInfos(Iter).Left * HorizRatio
      .Top = ControlInfos(Iter).Top * VertRatio
      .Width = ControlInfos(Iter).Width * HorizRatio
      .Height = ControlInfos(Iter).Height * VertRatio
      .FontSize = ControlInfos(Iter).FontSize * HorizRatio
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
  Next
  
End Sub
```

I tested this with the default form with a CommandButton, Frame, Timer, and TextBox, and it seemed to work OK.  You'll probably want to tune the limits on the minimum and maximum sizes for appearance, and my handling of the font is very crude; this could be optimized also.  But perhaps this could be a starting point.

This code depends upon the controls iterating the same way each time, which could conceivably break.  One way around this would be to use a Collection or other data structure with the name of the control as a key; when iterating in the .Resize event, each control would be looked up by name.  Additional structure will be necessary if any of the controls are themselves arrays, and even more if controls are loaded or unloaded dynamically.

Comment: it says runtime error '438' object doesnt support this property or metod

Comment: As with the Timer control, not all controls have all four properties (Top, Left, Width, and Height), so any control that doesn't will cause this error to occur.  You can either put in exceptions for those controls which don't have the necessary resizing properties, or take the easy (and only a little bit sleazy) way out and just wrap an On Error Resume Next around the With/End With statements in both the _Load and _Resize events.  (I'm sorry - although I updated my code to handle the Timer control, I forgot to update the code in the Answer - I'll do that now.)

Comment: @MarkMoulding - Good answer but I see a common refrain in your comment that could use a different perspective. In code, 'errors' are not occasions of shame or evidence of incompetence or laziness. They're *information* and can be very useful in just this sort of situation.

Comment: I have 2 questions, the first is How if the form_resize is removed? Because I set my form borderstye to none and it is maximized.  So i think i dont need the form_resize. the second, there is something error with the scale. It'ss scaled up to far. I saw small shape became so big.

Comment: All of my declared object error like ```x= x-1```.  Is it because I dont use like ```dim x as integer```. I never use it before because it will make my code be more longer and in my thought "It works even I dont use it".

Comment: @NevylloKalangi: To your first question, the Form_Resize event will fire any time the form's window boundaries change, which certainly happens with both Maximized and Minimized.  In the case of the latter, it's important not to try to resize the controls to follow, since the resultant Me.Height and Me.Width are very small (not zero, though).

Comment: @NevylloKalangi: In response to your second question, this is an issue of coding style.  Particularly in the case of VB, if a variable is not explicitly Dimensioned, it will be automatically created with a type of Variant, which is the least efficient type from a standpoint of processing speed and size.  In addition, it will automatically be initialized with a value of zero (if being used as a number).  This can lead to difficult-to-find bugs, especially in a large project, if a variable name is misspelled. You can make VB require this automatically: Tools|Options|Require variable declaration.

Comment: @JimMack: Thanks for the comment.  I understand and agree with your view; in this case, I'm being lazy because one tenet of "reliable programming" is that no return (or error) value be ignored, which is what I'm doing here.  Either the Err.Number should be validated to ensure it's a 438, or else prevented from happening in the first place (using If TypeOf ThisControl Is TextBox Or...)

Comment: @MarkMoulding Ok, i just want to make sure that ```Form_Resize``` will always be used. Cause im trying to make my code as neat and as short as I can. The code you give didn't really work with me. The form didn't scale to what i want. Is there any other way? To your second answer, That's a new thing for me, Thankyou. I will try to add dim to my project to minimalize the error.

Comment: So, I copied and pasted the code above into a new default project, and sprinkled a few random controls around the form - seemed to work fine.  (I did have to correct a minor syntax error - the GoTo in an On Error statement can't have a space.  The code above is corrected now.)  I don't know what else can be done...

Comment: And actually, contrary to my original description, indexed control arrays also work just fine.  There would still be additional structure needed for dynamically loaded controls, though.

Comment: @MarkMoulding How to make the controls scale up and down but the trigger isn't the form resize? Im trying to make it manual. I made a .txt file with a number, the bigger the number it will scale up further.